# PHP mail send file.html

Tags: php, html

Hello I am crating a simple PHP mail appi. To do so I have created a HTML form for Send To: input and Subject: input. now for the message I want to open a HTML file and be send to the reception. When i fill in the Send TO and Subject input field on index.php and submit it there is no errors, just the html file is displayed next page but no MAILS coming through.

I am working on localhost.

HTML file:

```
    <html>
<head></head>

<body>

<h2>Mail</h2>

<form name="form1" method="post" action="mail.php">
    Send To: <input type="text" id="recipient" name="recipient">
    <br>
    Subject: <input type="text" id="subject" name="subject">
    <br>
    <input type="submit" value="Send">

</form>

</body>

</html>
```

PHP file:

```
    <?php

$to = $_POST['recipient'];
$subject = $_POST['subject'];
$message = readfile("welcome.html","r") or exit ("Unable to open file");
fclose($message);


mail($to, $subject, $message);

?>
```

Could someone suggest a solution or direct me to a reading source on such topic.

Comment: At what point in the process does the failure occur?  Is there an error in the code?  Is there an error from the SMTP server?  If you point this at a test SMTP server, does it successfully receive the message as expected?  There are a lot of things that can prevent an email from displaying in your personal inbox, and very few of them have anything to do with the code.

Comment: Have you tried sending just a plain old email with a single character or word? If that doesn't work, your problem isn't sending a file's contents, it's sending anything. And if you're working on localhost, there's a good chance that's your problem.

Comment: have you also tried you use simple text before trying to read files etc once thats working then you can progress?

Comment: Hey as I said there is no error displayed so once again the process: Fill in the Html Form->Sendto->Subject->and the file.html is automatically opened and saved into $message variable which is part of mail(function). NO errors are shown everything looks as if it works but no mail in inbox

Comment: Look at the documentation. If you use [`readfile`](http://us2.php.net/readfile), you will only get an integer returned of the bytes that were read, however, if you use [`file_get_contents`](http://us3.php.net/file_get_contents), you see that the contents of the files would be returned as a string for your `$message` variable. This won't fix your `mail()` not sending, but you will find that the `$message` isn't what you expect it to be.

Comment: A meta-note: if what you have posted above is going to be placed on the internet for the world to see, then you are creating an open relay for people to send arbitrary emails to arbitrary recipients.

Comment: Yep I actually think the problem is with local host does anyone know how and where should i config ini.php to allow out band mails

Comment: ok combining few answers together i managed to get a Mail accros o my mail box but now the issue is the html file content does not appear it appears as a integer a number

Comment: http://us3.php.net/readfile The function returns the number of bytes read, not a string containing the contents of the file.

Comment: http://us3.php.net/manual/en/function.file-get-contents.php This is what you want to use instead.

Answer (score 0):

If you work on localhost, your internet box may block the port 25, which corresponds to the smtp mail port.

You should configure your box in order to open it, or test on a server which doesn't suffer from this configuration problem.

Comment: Yep I actually think the problem is with local host do you how and where should i config ini.php to allow out band mails

Comment: it's not in any ini.php, it's in your internet-box configuration. For example, in France I have a "livebox", and when I type "livebox" in my web-browser, I've the access to its configuration. It's the internet-box which blocks your mails, it's not a php problem.

Answer (score 0):

You are missing the `Content-Type` header to set the message as HTML. Plus, if you are working on your local machine you need to setup an SMTP server to send your emails.

```
$to = $_POST['recipient'];
$subject = $_POST['subject'];
$message = readfile("welcome.html","r") or exit ("Unable to open file");

$headers = "Content-type: text/html\r\n"; 

fclose($message);


mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers);
```

Comment: OK this works but Instead the html content I get a number integer not the content any idea ho i can fix it

Answer (score 0):

The others have helped you figure out your send problem, but as I indicated in my comments, you're using the wrong file-reading function. You should use `file_get_contents` instead, since that actually returns a string containing the file's contents, whereas your current solution returns an integer representing the number of bytes read. Try visiting https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.file-get-contents.php for more information.